# Error en extraer parámetros de un Uri en Android

Tags: java, android

Intento obtener los parámetros que conforman un `Uri` del estilo `mailto`

`mailto:\\email@website.com?title=titulo&body=cuerpo%20del%20email`

Quiero extraer el valor de `title`, `subject` y `body` pero detectando si existe el parámetro a extraer.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:\\email@website.com?title=titulo&body=cuerpo%20del%20email");

String tile = uri.getQueryParameter("title");
String body = uri.getQueryParameter("body");
```

pero si quiero extraer el `subject` que no está definido dentro del uri

```
String subject = uri.getQueryParameter("subject");
```

me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Process: com.webserveis.app.abouttemplate, PID: 25476
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This isn't a hierarchical
>   URI. at android.net.Uri.getQueryParameter(Uri.java:1665)

Supongo que lo devuelve porque no está declarado en la uri, ¿Cómo se puede detectar si está definido o no en el?

Comment: Tengo una duda, ¿lo que estás usando es realmente `Uri` o es `URI` del paquete `java.net`?, te lo pregunto porque los métodos `parse` y `getQueryParameter` no están definidos en la clase `URI` ¿podrías ampliar ese punto en tu pregunta?

Comment: Buenas @RosendoRopher uso android.net.Uri; mas o menos ya tengo la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido solventar, primero se debe consultar entre todos los parametros
        `Uri.getQueryParameterNames()`

Comprobar dentro del cojunto si el parametro consta:

`if (parameters.contains("title"))`

Una vez realizado se puede extraer su contenido con

`getQueryParameter(identificador)`

**Caso práctico**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:\\email@website.com?title=titulo&body=cuerpo%20del%20email");
if (uri.getQuery()!= null) {
    Set<String> parameters = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
    String title = parameters.contains("title") ? uri.getQueryParameter("title"): "";
    String subject = parameters.contains("body") ? uri.getQueryParameter("subject"): "";
    String body = parameters.contains("body") ? uri.getQueryParameter("body"): "";
}
```

Comment: Vale, me parece bien si el caso es que siempre serán los mismos parámetros, de no ser así puedes hacerlo más dinámico.